# help me to understand about the following sentence

Tags: sequences-and-series

In my book it is written that sum of odd terms  with $2n+1$ terms(total) in an Arthimetic Progression(A.P) is
$$S_1=a_1+a_3+a_5+\dots +a_{2n+1}$$
$$S_1=((n+1)/2)(a_1+a_{2n+1})$$ further after symplying it $$(n+1)(a+nd)$$ where $d$ is common difference.I don't understand  II step please some one explain it.

Comment: What do you mean by you "don't understand" the step. Do you not understand what it means, or do you not understand the proof?

Comment: @ S. Mo Yah I don't understand this proof

Comment: I don't think this _is_ a proof...

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a_n=a+(n-1)d$.

$a=a_1=a+0*d=a+(1-1)d$

Thus, $a_{2n+1}=a+(2n+1-1)d=a+2nd$, which if both are combined:

$a+a_{2n+1}=a+a+2nd=2a+2nd=2(a+nd)$

For where the 2 is coming from the cancel out the division part. Any part needing more elaboration?